# Filter and Combine Nested Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to combine the `gid` and `subGroups` and output it into an array of strings without duplication.
My problem now is that it only gets the first level.

```js
const oldGroup = [
    {
        "gid": "JFK",
        "subGroups": [
            "SFO",
            "LAX"
        ]
    },
    {
        "gid": "JFK",
        "subGroups": [
            "SFO",
            "LAX"
        ]
    },
    {
        "gid": "SFO",
        "subGroups": []
    },
    {
        "gid": "LAX",
        "subGroups": [
            "LGA"
        ]
    }
]

const newGroup = [...new Set(oldGroup.map((group) => group.gid))]

console.log(newGroup)
```

Comment: What’s the expected result? Are you looking for ``const newGroup = Array.from(new Set(oldGroup.flatMap(({ gid, subGroups }) => subGroups.map((item) => `${gid} → ${item}`))))``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.flatMap` instead of `.map`, return an array in the callback - the `.gid` value, and also spread in the `.subGroups` array.

```js
const oldGroup = [
    {
        "gid": "JFK",
        "subGroups": [
            "SFO",
            "LAX"
        ]
    },
    {
        "gid": "JFK",
        "subGroups": [
            "SFO",
            "LAX"
        ]
    },
    {
        "gid": "SFO",
        "subGroups": []
    },
    {
        "gid": "LAX",
        "subGroups": [
            "LGA"
        ]
    }
]

const newGroup = [...new Set(oldGroup.flatMap((group) => [group.gid, ...group.subGroups]))]

console.log(newGroup)
```

Comment: `Array.from(new Set(...))` maybe?

Comment: That's equivalent to `[...new Set()]` here

Comment: It seems harder to read, that might just be me.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this, here is one with `.reduce()`:

```js
const oldGroup = [
    { "gid": "JFK", "subGroups": [ "SFO", "LAX" ] },
    { "gid": "JFK", "subGroups": [ "SFO", "LAX" ] },
    { "gid": "SFO", "subGroups": [] },
    { "gid": "LAX", "subGroups": [ "LGA" ] }
];

const newGroup = Object.keys(oldGroup.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.gid] = true;
  obj.subGroups.forEach(name => { acc[name] = true; } );
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(newGroup)
```

Explanation:

- The `.reduce()` has two parameters:

  - a function parameter with two options `acc, obj`. The former is the accumulator that keeps track of the data needed, the latter is the array item object
  - an initial setting, and empty `{}` object in our case
- `Object.keys()` is applied on the accumulated data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.prototype.map() and Array.prototype.flat() methods to transform the oldGroup array into a new array that only contains the gid and subGroups values. You can then use the Array.prototype.filter() method to remove any duplicate values from the new array.

```
const oldGroup = [
    {
        "gid": "JFK",
        "subGroups": [
            "SFO",
            "LAX"
        ]
    },
    {
        "gid": "JFK",
        "subGroups": [
            "SFO",
            "LAX"
        ]
    },
    {
        "gid": "SFO",
        "subGroups": []
    },
    {
        "gid": "LAX",
        "subGroups": [
            "LGA"
        ]
    }
]
// Transform the oldGroup array into a new array that only contains the gid and subGroups values
const newGroup = oldGroup.map(group => [group.gid, ...group.subGroups]).flat();

// Remove any duplicate values from the new array
const dedupedGroup = newGroup.filter((value, index) => newGroup.indexOf(value) === index);

console.log(dedupedGroup); // ["JFK", "SFO", "LAX", "SFO", "LAX", "SFO", "LAX", "LGA"]
```